# Simple script crashes blender when I run it?

Tags: python

I am following a tutorial series on learning python for blender. The next part of the tutorial is creating a circle and to try and learn better I work ahead, but whenever I try to run my script it crashes blender so it's tough to troubleshoot what the problem is?

```
import bpy
import math

#get the vertex positions
verts = []
edges = []
faces = []
points = 10
for i in range(points):
    rad = math.radians((i/points)*360)
    x = math.cos(rad)
    y = math.sin(rad)
    z = 0
    coordinates = [x,y,z]
    verts.append(coordinates)
    edges.append([i-1,i])
    
            
#create the empty data for the circle
meshData = bpy.data.meshes.new('cube_data')
#add the vertex and edge data for the circle
meshData.from_pydata(verts,edges,faces)
#create an object and link the mesh data
meshObj = bpy.data.objects.new('cube_object',meshData)
#link the object to the collection
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(meshObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your edge list is malformed.
The initial `edges.append([i-1,i])` gives the first edge index a vertex index of -1, which makes Blender upset when linking the object to a collection.

Comment out `bpy.context.collection.objects.link(meshObj)` and print your list of edges and see for yourself
`print("edges:", edges)`